# Highstock giving error 15

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I added two time series in highstock , but after running the sample , I get this error ***: Highcharts error #15*** in console also browser does not show properly.I checked for this error but time series data is in ascending order only, so could not make out why this error coming up ?

```
$('#chartdiv').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 2
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'test highchart'
    },
    series: seriesOptions
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/0tfkfh2v/3/) is the fiddle for above issue.

Comment: "but the time series data is in ascending order only" -- no it is not. `1437955200000, 1431907200000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `timeArr` array isn't sorted actually. Just adding this line gets rid of the error:

```
timeArr.sort();
```

See your [updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0tfkfh2v/6/).

Comment: thanks for reply , I also require to color bar graph depending upon value , so if threshold is 5 , then y values bar should show red else green. I tried adding { threshold: 5,  negativeColor: 'red', color: 'green' } to series data , it plots values with color , but  red values get plotted on negative side, is there way to plot all bars on same axis and color as per threshold . here is the fiddle that I tried : http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/0tfkfh2v/8/

Comment: You can use [zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones) option.

Comment: @Bhupendra *zones* are probably the best, as said Sebastian Bochan. Something like: `zones: [{value: 5, color: 'red' }, {color: 'green'}]` should give you want you want.

Comment: @SebastianBochan;@kabulan0ak  Thanks for your suggestions , it worked well